# Windows 7 touch emulate mouse

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchscreen

I have recently bought a small 10" capacitive touchscreen which works in windows 7 with the native HID touch support.

For my application, I dont need multi-touch support at all. I need it to exactly clone the mouse, i.e. when i press my finger on the screen, it registers as a "mouse-down" and release registers as a "mouse-up" and moves the mouse pointer to where I have touched.

I have tried playing with all the options available in "Pen and touch" but none of them make the touch screen function this way.

Previous touchscreens I've used with this setup have had third party drivers ("egalax touch" or "touchkit" for example) which disable the native windows touch and make the screen function as I need.

Unfortunately this display is made by a different manufacturer and there seems to be no 3rd party drivers available.

Is there a way to make the native touch in windows behave as I describe above? I've searched for things like "windows 7 HID emulate mouse" etc but I can't find a solution.