# WM_TOUCH to WM_LBUTTONDOWN

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen, input, on-screen-keyboard

One of the strange behaviors I find on my Windows 10 device with a touchscreen is pressing on the touchscreen and having no mouse-button down event triggered. For example, I use an app called Caustic which has an onscreen keyboard which you can play using the mouse. However, the touchscreen doesn't work when I set my finger down on the screen and no note is played. It's waiting instead to see if I drag my finger before I lift it back up. The [Press and Hold settings](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/disable-or-enable-press-and-hold-for-right-clicking-in-win-10.html) promise to remedy the problem, but to no avail. Instead of showing a big rectangle when I press and hold, if I hold very still, a tiny circle appears (in a clockwise animation even), but still no mouse-down event occurs.

If it matters, I have an MS Surface Book. If no know solution exists, I was thinking maybe a program could dll inject and modify the message queue to insert WM_LBUTTONDOWN messages whenever a WM_TOUCH message is seen.

Comment: Some developer chat around this, but not much help to the end user: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/cdc3ace3-a3c6-4ff3-8bb4-c79cf31da3f0/touch-input-wmlbuttondown-delayed-even-after-disabling-flicks-and-pressandhold?forum=tabletandtouch

Comment: Similar but for Windows 7 http://superuser.com/questions/871297/windows-7-touch-emulate-mouse?rq=1